# Datepicker campo dinámico

Tags: php, javascript, datepicker

Buenas tardes,

Estoy generando un formulario que tiene varios campos datepicker que podrán ir añadiéndose al pulsar sobre un botón "más". Al pulsar dicho botón, el campo se me duplica correctamente pero no consigo que sea de tipo datepicker. Os dejo el código a ver si podéis ayudarme pues no veo el fallo y le he dado mil vueltas. Muchas gracias de antemano

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $.datepicker.regional['es'] = {
         closeText: 'Cerrar',
         prevText: '<Ant',
         nextText: 'Sig>',
         currentText: 'Hoy',
         monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
         monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr', 'May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep', 'Oct','Nov','Dic'],
         dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
         dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mié','Juv','Vie','Sáb'],
         dayNamesMin: ['Do','Lu','Ma','Mi','Ju','Vi','Sá'],
         weekHeader: 'Sm',
         dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
         firstDay: 1,
         isRTL: false,
         showMonthAfterYear: false,
         yearSuffix: ''
        };


        $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['es']);

        $(function() {
            $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["es"]);
            $( ".fecha" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'});         

        });

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['es']);
            $(function() {
                $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["es"]);
                $( "#otra_fecha" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'});            

            });

            var maxField = 10; //Input fields increment limitation
            var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
            var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
            var fieldHTML = '<div><input type="text" name="notif_perito" id="otra_fecha" class="fecha" /><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove field"><img src="<?= $_SESSION['ruta_img'];?>minus.gif"/></a></div>'; //New input field html 
            var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1



            $(addButton).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
                if(x < maxField){ //Check maximum number of input fields
                    x++; //Increment field counter
                    $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); // Add field html
                }
            });

            $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){ //Once remove button is clicked
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
                x--; //Decrement field counter
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema reside en que construyes el componente datepicker **ANTES** de que el elemento se haya creado.

Una forma rápida y sencilla de solucionarlo es activando el datepicker para cada elemento que se añada.

Modificando esta línea del código:

```
$(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); // Add field html
```

Por esta otra:

```
$(wrapper).append($(fieldHTML).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'})); // Add field html
```

Ya deberías de tener el problema resuelto.
Lo podríamos hacer en dos pasos si así lo ves más claro:

```
var fieldHTML_datepicker = $(fieldHTML).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'}); // Campo con el datepicker asociado
$(wrapper).append(fieldHTML_datepicker); // Add field html
```

De este modo, le aplicamos el `datepicker` a todos los elementos nuevos que se vayan creado.

### ACTUALIZACIÓN:

La variable `fieldHTML` contiene más nodos aparte del input, por lo que el `datepicker` se está aplicando al `div` lo cual no es lo deseado. Para evitar este problema, tendríamos que partir el `html` que estás añadiendo para que el `datepicker` se lo activemos únicamente al `input`.

Para ello, rompemos la línea donde construimos el `html` en dos partes:

```
var fieldContainerHTML = '<div><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove field"><img src="minus.gif"/></a></div>';
var fieldInputHTML = '<input type="text" name="notif_perito" id="otra_fecha" class="fecha" />';
```

Y en la línea donde los añadimos al documento lo hacemos por pasos también:

```
var fieldContainer = $(fieldContainerHTML); //Construimos el objeto jquery y lo guardamos en una variable para hacer referencia después.
var fieldInput = $('<input type="text" name="notif_perito" id="otra_fecha" class="fecha" />').datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'}); // Construimos el input y le asociamos el datepicker
fieldContainer.prepend(fieldInput); // Añadimos el input al html contenedor
$(wrapper).append(fieldContainer); // Añadimos los nodos html al wrapper
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @frikinside ! Al activar el datepicker de la forma en que me indicas, automáticamente al pulsar el botón más del formulario me aparece el calendario para escoger la fecha. Ahora el problema es que aunque seleccione una fecha en concreto, no se muestra "escrita" en el input. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Tienes razón @Lis86 no me fijé bien en el HTML que guardas en `fieldHTML`. He hecho una actualización para que le añadas el `datepicker` únicamente al input y de ese modo, te funcione correctamente. Coméntame si te funciona o te encuentras algún problema con ello.

Comment: te quiero! <3 funciona correctamente. Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Nada hombre, sin problemas. Uno se alegra de resultar útil.

Comment: @frikinside Hola frink, veo que ayudaste a una compañera de esta comunidad, estoy trabajando con el mismo tipo de código, peor aun tengo unos problemas me podrías ayudar por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Cada datepicker que aparezca en la página debería tener un id único, si todos tienen el mismo id sólo aperecerá una vez. Prueba a darles una id propia a cada uno y utilízala para inicializarlos.

Puedes ver aquí un ejemplo:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22828994/5675636

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder. Esto ya lo probé y tampoco funciona en el caso del "campo dinámico". Pero muchas gracias por guiarme!